# Reactjs: why is this not working in class component but working in functional component

Tags: reactjs

why is this not working in the class component but working in the functional component?

> Functional Component(working)

```js
export default function App() {
  const initCols = [
    {
      name: 'name',
    },
  ];
  const [cols, setCols] = useState(initCols); // works
}
```

> ClassComponent(not working)

```js
class testclass extends Component {
  const initCols = [
  {
    name: "name"
  }];
  state = {cols: initCols}   // donot work
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what is "not working"?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot define const values in class component because it is a [class](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) but you can do it that way:

```
 state = {
    cols: [
      {
        name: "name"
      }
    ]
  };
```

Is there any reason that you have to have it in const variable?

You can also define it before a component and then use it like:

```
const initCols = [
{
    name: "name"
}];

class testclass extends Component {
 state = {cols: initCols}
```

Comment: Great but might not prefer to do this as it will increase the size of stata{} to multiple rows if the number of cols is more. so added my solution below

Comment: But now it leads to another problem. now if I try to access functions using this , i get '''this is undefined here''':

cols: [
      {
        name: "name",
        customBodyRender: (tableMeta) => {
              this.renderEmpData(tableMeta.rowData[2])
      }
    ]

this is undefined here

Answer (score 0):

> // This works

```
const initCols = [
{
    name: "name"
}];
class testclass extends Component {
state = {cols: initCols}
....
```